# How to increase font size of text in watermarking text over an image in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have written a code in codeigniter to write text over the image using watermarking text in CI, I have pasted the code which I have written.

```
 $imgpath = './images/posters/'.$filename;

  $newimgpath = './images/wm/'.$filename;


  $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
  $config['source_image'] = $imgpath;
  $config['wm_text'] = $ref_id;
  $config['wm_type'] = 'text';
  $config['new_image'] = $newimgpath;
  $config['width']  = '50';
  $config['wm_font_path'] = './media/texb.ttf';
  $config['wm_font_size'] = '16';
  
  $config['wm_shadow_color'] = '993300';
  $config['wm_shadow_distance'] = '3';


  $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
  $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
  $config['wm_font_color'] = '#FFFFFF';
  $config['wm_hor_offset'] = '350';
  $config['wm_vrt_offset'] = '30';
  $config['wm_padding'] = '-300';
```

The problem is that the text written over the image is small in size and not visible. How to increase the size of the text ? Is there any solution for this ?
Even if it is increased from 16 ,,the size of the text is not increasing. Any solution for this ?

I have changed some codes in the image library in the library folder in the system folder but it is not working.

The screenshot is included as below :

[image]

I have circled where the text has been written but the font is small.

Comment: [From the docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html) for `wm_font_size`: *Note: If you are not using the True Type option above, the number is set using a range of 1 - 5.* You are not using a true type font, so you should be using size 1-5, I guess? Have you tried that?

Comment: yes...I have tried it..I have made it as 4...but its the same.

Comment: Also I have given a ttf font path..and increased the font size to 20..but its still not working....